# How to do slice operation in 2D array of c++ the same as Python

Tags: c++, arrays

experts. I have a 2D data array:vertices, and a 2D index array:faces. How can I do slice operation?

```
data array: vertices
0.041159 -0.342570 1.029412 
0.015579 -0.341674 1.077751
0.014664 -0.341184 1.031222
0.041923 -0.343100 1.073583
0.064655 -0.344713 1.068008

index array:faces
0 1 3
2 1 4
1 2 3
```

In Python, we can get all vertices of first, second, last column of faces with:

```
v0 = vertices[faces[:,0],:]
v1 = vertices[faces[:,1],:]
v2 = vertices[faces[:,2],:]
```

How can I do above slice operation in C++?

```
std::vector<std::vector<double > > vertices //2D data array
std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int> >  faces; // 2D index array
```

Comment: You can do indexing but not slicing in C++, unless you're willing to use `std::valarray` which provide a `slice()` operation but come with their own caveats.

Comment: Thanks, @Tharsalys, could you please give me more details? You means I can get the data[1][2] with index = 1*3+1?

Comment: No, you can get `data[1][2]` with `data[1][2]` but for something more fancy like `data[1:3][2]`, you'll have to do some indexing/iterator gymnastics. Or alternatively, you can also layout your arrays contiguously (1-d fashion), and then do what you said `data[1*3 + 1]` to access the third element in the second row.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot @Tharsalys. Have a good day.

Comment: Hi,@Tharsalys, can I use a point to indexing like this *p = data[0][0]. Within p, we can access the data[1][2] with p[1*3+1]?

Comment: It depends on what the type of `data` is and whether its memory-layout is contiguous. Given your example of 2-d vectors, it wouldn't work, because while elements within a vector are contiguous in memory, it's not guaranteed that the elements across vectors would be contiguous as well. For example, `vertices[0]` can be on an entirely different block than `vertices[1]` (you can try having a pointer to `vertices[0][0]` and then increment it to see when it crosses over its block). If you insist on using pointers, I recommend default arrays.

Comment: You can write a type that accepts a `Slice` object in it's `operator[]`, and returns an object that references that slice of data. You could even write it as a wrapper that takes anything with a `operator[]` and maps a range of indexes

Comment: There is also the option of using some library target at working matrices, such as [armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/), [eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page), etc.. But if all you need is just the indexing (and not power linear algebra stuff in them), then it's probably not worth it adding such dependency to your project.